# Raspberry pi3 12v led circuit - broke down pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, 12v, switching

I wanted to use 12v led, so I tried to switching 5v(gpio pin) to 12v.

This is my 12v switching circuit.
[image]

And this circuit broke down my raspberry pi.
When I wired this circuit, they worked well. But I switched on and off several times, the transistor and raspberry pi broke down.

Why my raspberry pi and transistor died??

Comment: What pins on the RPi were you using?

Comment: PS. The RPI uses 3.3V not 5V.  It doesn't explain why it died in this case though.

Comment: You need 330 ohm resistors (or more), the max limit of output current is 16mA, safe limit is 8mA. That would only explain dead GPIO pins however.

Comment: @OskarSkog I used 22 pin.

Comment: @user2497 Max limit that you said is gpio pin's or transistor's? If gpio pin, I used gpio pin only output.. So I cannot understand why gpio pin died.

Comment: @juae If too much current is sourced, the pin is fried. Perhaps more gets fried. 3.3/220=15mA, so it’s close to max.

Comment: Isn’t the 2222a a max 200mA NPN? I think it is. Consider using logic level mosfet to switch power mosfet. Remember pull-down and a resistor to protect against surge to gate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When those transistors are turned on, there's what amounts to a short circuit through the associated LED to ground. You need an appropriately sized resistor in series with those LEDs.

I suspect what happened (the failure mode you experienced) is that the transistors got damaged by overcurrent, and the failed transistor inadvertently fed 12V back into your GPIO pin and that baked your Pi.

Comment: Why transistor causes overcurrent?
Current flows led to emitter?
And how to know appropriately sized resistor?
Thanks!

Comment: what kind of an LED runs on 12V ?

Comment: @jsotola A lot of LEDs run on 12V lol :) car LEDs is a good example. And it's not as simple as Ohm's Law. One should research about the _modes of operation_ for a BJT transistor.

Comment: @jsotola I used led in push button switch; looks like this[ https://kr.misumi-ec.com/linked/material/el/HNX1/PHOTO/HNX1_16PJ_17059_IMAGE3.jpg?$product_main$ ]

Comment: @KingDuken My led's current consumption is 18mA!
How do I get resister size? :)

Comment: @juae keep your load between Vsrc and collector, connect emitter to ground.

Comment: @KingDuken, it does boil down to ohm's law. always assume that the transistor is effectively a short circuit when turned on, calculate the resistor value and give the circuit a try. that way you do not blow up the LED (you may fry the transistor though)